# How get XDocument from file with xml content (*.zip and other)?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

It work for *.xml files:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(file.InputStream);
```

How get XDocument from file with xml content (*.zip and other)?

Comment: If you are using .net 4.5, you can use the ZipArchive in system.IO.Compression to extract the zip first.

Comment: @BytesOracle Actually, `ZipArchive`. But close enough.

Comment: @It'sNotALie, you're right I'm gonna edit that comment.

Comment: @PacMani I have xml code in .xml file which is packed!!

Comment: @Olena: How can XML code be packed? You mean you have a CDATA section with packed zip bytes? Can you post an example please?

Comment: @PacMani  You can package any file with an archiver. For example http://vk.com/doc90589251_212832152   What do you think about it?

Comment: @Olena: Yeah but you have to unpack it first to parse XML out of it, as the answer below tells you for example.

Comment: @PacMani you are the captain obvious =)

Comment: @Olena: That's what you didn't make clear :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) class:

```
var zArch = new ZipArchive(file.InputStream);
XDocument xDoc = null;
using (var stream = zArch.GetEntry("yourFile.xml").Open())
    xDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
if (xDoc != null) //be safe not sorry
    //manipulate the XDocument.
```